# Printing an error message on screen using Wicket

Tags: java, wicket

So, I got a wicket page with some components I can update, and some of them updates automatically.

```
this.getFieldOneInput().add(new AjaxFormComponentUpdatingBehavior("onchange") {
    @Override
    protected void onUpdate(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
        Panel.this.populateFieldTwo(target);
        Panel.this.populateFieldThree(target);
    }
});
```

There is an auto complete feature so I can fill my field on with available objects from DB. And every time i change my field one value, I will also populate fields two and three.

But I need to do something else here. I need to check if the chose object for field on got some null valued attribute. If any of its attribute is null, I want to show an error message on screen: "FieldOne attribute X is null". I want it to be shown on screen like those red wicket messages when some field is required.

How can I do that?

Comment: checkout wicket validators...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By using the Wicket `FeedbackPanel`

HTML:

```
<div wicket:id="feedback"></div>
```

Page:

Add a new FeedbackPanel, and just do `error(message)`

Reference: http://www.wicket-library.com/wicket-examples/compref/wicket/bookmarkable/org.apache.wicket.examples.compref.FormPage?0